# How Do I Detect Swamps in Screeps

Tags: screeps

In screeps, I can see swamps using my browser window. However, I can find no way for my script to detect if the terrain is a swamp except for having my creeps walk around marking swamps they encounter as they go. Are there any other ways to detect swamps?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Room.lookForAt`](https://docs.screeps.com/api/#Room.lookForAt) method:

```
var terrain = creep.room.lookForAt('terrain', creep.pos.x+1, creep.pos.y);
if(terrain != 'swamp') {
  creep.move(RIGHT);
}
```

If you want to find all terrain tiles from the entire room, check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351798/how-to-find-all-swamp-squares-in-a-screeps-room/30045521).